# "Could you **please** provide me the details......"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, formality, politeness

When we write a business email and want some information from the mail recipient, then which is the most professional way to ask for information? Does using "please" in a sentence make it look bad?

Comment: Have you never received a formal letter that ends with something like *Please sign and return the attached form*? Why would you think a bit of politeness was "bad"?

Comment: I would use "Could you provide me **with** the details...?" as "Could you..." is polite enough. Using "please" doesn't make it look bad.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you don't capitalize it, it's fine:

> Could you please provide me the details?

It's not at all necessary, though, and in fact the word "please" can convey a sense of impatience or insistence. So it ironically could be a bit more polite to just say

> Could you provide me the details?

Beginning the request with "Could you..." is actually more important for courtesy than saying "Please".

Answer (score 1):

No, the use of the word *please* implies both respect and having manners. However whether or not you should use *please* depends on the position you're in.

For example, you wouldn't tell your boss to give you the details, you would ask for the details. Since this is your boss you would show respect, in which case *please* would be included in a proper response.

If you're above someone in position, e.g. the boss or employer, you would need to ask or force respect on your employers--a bit biased. As an employer or boss you'd need to order your employees to do their job and get you the details.